# Ember.js: Summarize model records into one record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I thought I had this figured out using `reduce()`, but the twist is that I need to roll up multiple properties on each record, so every time I am returning an object, and the problem I'm having is that `previousValue` is an Ember Object, and I'm returning a plain object, so it works fine on the first loop, but the second time through, `a` is no longer an Ember object, so I get an error saying `a.get is not a function`. Sample code:

```
/*
filter the model to get only one food category, which is determined by the user selecting a choice that sets the property: theCategory 
*/
var foodByCategory = get(this, 'model').filter(function(rec) {
  return get(rec, 'category') === theCategory;
});

/*
Now, roll up all the food records to get a total
of all cost, salePrice, and weight
*/
summary = foodByCategory.reduce(function(a,b){
  return {
    cost: a.get('cost') + b.get('cost'),
    salePrice: a.get('salePrice') + b.get('salePrice'),
    weight: a.get('weight') + b.get('weight')
  };
});
```

Am I going about this all wrong? Is there a better way to roll up multiple records from the `model` into one record, or do I just need to either flatten out the model records into plain objects first, or alternatively, return an Ember object in the `reduce()`?

**Edit:** doing `return Ember.Object.create({...})` does work, but I still would like some opinion on whether this is the best way to achieve the goal, or if Ember provides functions that will do this, and if so, if they're any better than `reduce`.

Comment: Are you using ember data?

Comment: @locks: in my controller

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `this.get('model')` returns an `Ember.Enumerable`, you can use [filterBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filterBy) instead of `filter`:

```
var foodByCategory = get(this, 'model').filterBy('category', theCategory);
```

As for your `reduce`, I don't know of any Ember built-ins that would improve it. The best I can think of is using multiple, separate `mapBy` and `reduce` calls:

```
summary =  {
  cost: foodByCategory.mapBy('cost').reduce(...),
  salePrice: foodByCategory.mapBy('salePrice').reduce(...),
  ...
};
```

But that's probably less performant. I wouldn't worry too much about using Ember built-ins to do standard data manipulation... most Ember projects I know of still use a utility library (like Lodash) alongside Ember itself, which usually ends being more effective when writing this sort of data transformation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm fine with it being plain JavaScript to roll up the data. In your opinion, is `reduce()` the best way to do that? In essence I'm trying to create a new model with a single record. I'm also adding in additional properties to `summary` based on the rolled-up properties. Should I do this in the route instead, roll up by Category there, and then just `filterBy` in the Controller?

Comment: @redOctober13 depends on what you mean by "best". `reduce` is definitely a good way to do it. I'm not sure I have enough context to say what's best for your situation, but it sounds like "summary" is a first-class Object in your app, even if it's not a model. I'd consider creating a Summary "class" as `const Summary = Ember.Object.extend({...`, so you can define Computed Properties there in a more OO way. Then you can do something like `summary = Summary.create(foodByCategory.reduce(...))`, where your `reduce` returns a POJO. Let me know if my comment's not clear.

Comment: @redOctober13 Oh, something else: you may find http://emberjs.com/api/#method_get (`Ember.get(obj, key)`) useful: it will work on both POJOs and `Ember.Object`s.